# Get a specific child tag from a DOMElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am walking through a xml definition file and I have a DOMNodeList that I am walking through.
I need to extract the contents of a child tag that may or may not be in the current entity

```
<input id="name">
  <label>Full Name:</label>
  <required />
</input>
<input id="phone">
  <required />
</input>
<input id="email" />
```

I need to replace ????????????? with something that gets me the contents of the label tag if 
it exists.

Code:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('required') as $required){
  $curr = $required->parentNode;

  $label[$curr->getAttribute('id')] = ?????????????
}
```

Expected Result:

```
Array(
  ['name'] => "Full Name:"
  ['phone'] => 
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange thing is: you already know the answer since you've used it in your script, [getElementsByTagName()](http://docs.php.net/domelement.getelementsbytagname).
But this time not with the DOMDocument as context "node" but with the `input` DOMElement:

```
<?php
$doc = getDoc();
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('required') as $e ) {
  $e = $e->parentNode; // this should be the <input> element
  // all <label> elements that are direct children of this <input> element
  foreach( $e->getElementsByTagName('label') as $l ) {
    echo 'label="', $l->nodeValue, "\"\n";
  }
}

function getDoc() {
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->loadxml('<foo>
    <input id="name">
      <label>Full Name:</label>
      <required />
    </input>
    <input id="phone">
      <required />
    </input>
    <input id="email" />
  </foo>');
  return $doc;
}
```

prints `label="Full Name:"`

Comment: Rock, that will do it, Thanks!