# XML Import via PHP

Tags: php, xml, import

I've got some XML that looks a bit like this:

```
<item code="1">
  <description>This is an item.</description>
  <prices>
     <price nett="1.50"/>
     <price code="RPP" nett="20.33" />
  </prices>
</item>
```

And I'm trying to import it into our DB using PHP like this:

```
$xmlurl = 'thexmlfile.xml';

$dom = new DOMDocument();   
$dom->load($xmlurl);

$records = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($records as $record) {

    $descs = $record-> getElementsByTagName('description');
    $desc = $descs->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $desc . '<br />';  

}
```

That works fine. It pulls the description. However, how do I get the item code and the prices section? Loop within a loop?]

Thank you

Comment: But... none of your elements have id `description`.

Comment: Can an item have multiple prices?

Comment: @WaleedKhan edited... :/

Comment: @Awemo - yes mate , hence the "prices" element.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** I corrected the code, iterating through the prices for each item separately.

To get the item code, do the following;

```
$record->getAttribute('code');
```

You can loop through the prices of this item by looping within the loop like you said. To access the prices do the following;

```
$pricesTag = $record->getElementsByTagName('prices');
$prices = $pricesTag->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('price');
```

Then repeat the shenanigans of looping and accessing the node values and attributes of the prices all over.

Source: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816806/get-a-specific-child-tag-from-a-domelement-in-php)

Working example: [corrected code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8jCHfQ)

Comment: Hi @Awemo, i've just discovered this doesn't work when I have more than 1 item. It loops through all the Prices... any fix?